# How to link native DLL to C# class with *char data

Tags: c#, native, dllimport

I have this native interface:

```
void CLASS_Version(char *Version);
```

I tried to import it with:

```
[DllImport("class.dll", EntryPoint = "CLASS")]
private static extern void CLASS_Version(ref string[] Version);
```

or

```
[DllImport("class.dll", EntryPoint = "CLASS")]
private static extern void CLASS_Version(ref char[] Version);

[DllImport("class.dll", EntryPoint = "CLASS")]
private static extern void CLASS_Version(out string[] Version);

[DllImport("class.dll", EntryPoint = "CLASS")]
private static extern void CLASS_Version(out char[] Version);
```

But I alway get "AccessViolation" error,
The only good run was made with

```
[DllImport("class.dll", EntryPoint = "CLASS")]
private static extern void CLASS_Version(ref char Version);
```

but this way I got only the first char of the strings... how to get all string?

Comment: Why not just a `string`?

Comment: Because string is not mutable.  You must pass a StringBuilder with a sufficient Capacity.  No *ref* or *out*.  And say a little prayer that it won't corrupt the GC heap, aim that Capacity high.

Comment: For a start I'd like to point out that `EntryPoint` should `= "CLASS_Version"` if that's the method name. If you're using the same method name when declaring it you don't even need to define the `EntryPoint` property, it's only needed if you are renaming the function out of choice or due to a breaking name change in the native code that you don't want to replicated in the managed code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char *` is ambiguous, but it definitely isn't an array of strings. Most likely, it's a pointer to a string, so you'll use just a simple `StringBuilder` (no `ref` or `out`).

Also, make sure to use the proper marshalling attributes. .NET strings are always widechars, unlike your signature.

In general, a signature of a function *isn't enough* for proper interop with native code. You need to understand the meaning of the arguments and the return values, and you need to know the calling convention. You need to read the documentation, in other words :)

Comment: I believe if you get the calling convention wrong, the CLR will give you an exception explaining exactly that. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Only if you are very lucky. If you are unlucky, one random day it will crush randomly. Or perhaps you'll change from 32 to 64 bits and everything will go boom.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis There's no way to know with native endpoints. There's no metadata, and no way to "infer" if your calling convention "worked". This has always been a problem with native code - avoiding problems like this was one of the motivations behind the design of the JVM and .NET CLR. Imagine how it would work - the callee expects parameters on the stack, and the caller supplies them in registers. The callee pops parameters from the stack (there's always something to pop :P), and both see valid(ish) states. In debug mode, .NET warns you about the stack imbalance, but that's it.

Comment: *You need to read the documentation, in other words :)* Not only this... 9 times out of 10 you have to go well beyond the documentation. Just the question "who will free that string and how" should be enough to keep you awake,

Comment: @Luaan Well before JVM and .NET CLR it was the reason for COM

Comment: @xanatos Hah, yeah. I'm of course referring to the magical fairy tale documentation that *actually helps you solve your problem*. In truth, I had to decompile quite a few libraries to understand their ownership and parameter passing semantics. Just thinking about it makes me cringe. And yeah, .NET is basically COM 2.0 :D AFAIK it was even referred to as such when the project was starting.

Comment: @Luaan I have to say the Windows API MSDN documentation is nearly fairy tale level for this. Sadly that is one of the very few documentations of this level I've ever seen.

Comment: Interesting, I thought the CLR did some magic to guarantee that exception in case of stack unbalancing due to P/Invoke. Turns out that this is triggered only in very specific circumstances. I guess I really *was* lucky when I saw it!

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis You're not the only one in that case. So far every time I've used the wrong calling convention I've had that exact same "stack unbalance" message. Thankfully APIs tend to use the same calling convention for everything so I only make that mistake once per API.

Comment: The answer was: private static extern void CLASS_Version(StringBuilder version);  (without ref or out)

Comment: @Pharap Yeah, stack imbalance is fairly easy to detect most of the time (basically, when execution returns to the P/Invoke wrapper, you check if the stack pointer is the same as after the prologue), and quite a common occurence when there's a calling convention mismatch.

Comment: It would never be `ref string`. That would map to `char**` and would require the string to have been allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc`.

Comment: @Luaan Most likely because 7 times out of 10 the calling conventions being used are `cdecl` or WINAPI/`stdcall`. The discrepency comes from  `cdecl` expecting the caller to clean the stack, and `stdcall` expecting the callee to clean the stack. In order for it to not be noticed you'd have to be using less common calling conventions. For example if you mixed up `Pascal` and `stdcall` where the only difference is the direction the parameters are passed, the problem would be a lot harder to track down.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right, fixed :) I never ever used `string` when receiving text from interop - it just sounded like a horrible idea from the get-go :D

Comment: @Pharap Uncommon is very relative. I've dealt with Pascal calling conventions quite frequently. C++'s thiscall is also an issue, though few people try to use thiscall from C#. You'll still find a problem quite quickly if you actually check the inputs and outputs, but as we learned from C's history, most people focus on the happy path and ignore possible issues until they actually happen. The two main issues are "who cleans the stack" and "what's passed in registers, and what's passed on the stack and in which order". 64-bit makes this a lot simpler, at least. On Windows. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically pointers are represented with `IntPtr` type. 
plus, the entry point should be the string representing the function name

try:

```
[DllImport("class.dll", EntryPoint = "CLASS_Version")]
private static extern void CLASS_Version(IntPtr Version);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[DllImport("class.dll", EntryPoint = "CLASS")]
private static extern void CLASS_Version([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string Version);
```

And when you are going to call your method:

```
Version = Space(14);// first declare memory space requiered ¿14 bytes? ¿more?
CLASS_Version(Version);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the answer cannot be determined by type alone.
If it were that simple there would be parsers that could write the native wrapper for you.
The type you have to use depends on what the function is actually doing.

In your case the `char *` is not marked `const`, and it is being accepted as a parameter, which implies that it's intended to be a user-allocated area of memory available for the function to write to. As there is no size parameter, there is most likely a maximum size that the version string can be, which *should* be indicated in the documentation of the code.

Given that this is string handling, you also have to worry about the encoding. For the sake of simplicity I'm going to assume (and hope) your string is in ASCII/Windows-1252 and not UTF8, UTF7 or some other format.

Given these assumptions, you have several options, but I will be presenting just the preferred way of handling this based on the information provided. (It may be that your situation requires something different, but this is the best solution I can suggest based on asumptions inferred from the information in your question.)

```
[DllImport("class.dll", EntryPoint = "CLASS_Version", , CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] // CharSet is important
private static extern void CLASS_Version(StringBuilder Version);
```

This is the 'correct' way to manage the situation - rely on the compiler to handle the marshalling for you. One small caveat however is that you must manually set the capacity of the StringBuilder before passing it to the method.

```
// be sure to allocate a correct size,
// there will be no error if it overflows because it's too small
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(size); 
// automagically marshalled to and from unmanaged code byt the compiler
CLASS_Version(buffer);
string version = buffer.ToString();
```

I'd like to take this opportunity to point out that `CLASS_Version` shouldn't be `private`. All your native methods should be made `public` and grouped together in one `internal static class`.

Some additional resources about string marshalling that you may find handy:
https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/using-the-stringbuilder-in-unmanaged-api-calls/